# TypeError: url() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Прохожу гайд по книге Эрика Метиза по работе с фреймворком Django, в ходе работы возникла ошибка, не могу решить проблему, начав поиск в интернете, наткнулся на [статью](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48271543/typeerror-url-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-name-space).

**learning_log\urls.py**

```py
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.template.defaulttags import url
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('learning_logs.urls')),
]
```

**learning_logs\urls.py**

```py
from django.template.defaulttags import url
from . import views

app_name = 'learning_logs'
urlpatterns = {
    # Домашняя страница
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
}
```

**views.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import rende

def index(request):
    """Домашняя страница для learning_logs"""
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/index.html')
```

При запуске сервера с помощью команды `python manage.py runserver` получаю следующую ошибку:

```py
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
TypeError: url() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
```

В виртуальном окружении я использую:

- `Django 4.0.1`
- `Python 3.9`

P.S.: Я так полагаю, что проблема в разнице версий, но я совсем новичок и не понимаю, что от меня просят.

Comment: Почему в файле `learning_logs\urls.py` Вы используете словарь вместо списка? Это опечатка, или у Вас в коде так же?

Comment: @nomnoms12 спасибо, исправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправил самостоятельно
**leagrning_logs\urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path


from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # Домашняя страница
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

По книге идёт старая версия Django с версии 3.0 как я понял рекомендуется использовать path
**learning_log\urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('learning_logs.urls')),
]
```